# sqlite get data from one field on two different dates and present as two columns

Tags: sqlite, time-series

I have a sqlite database with some time series data:

```
holdings:
| id  |  date | instrument | position | price | portfolio | sector |

prices:
| id  | date  | instrument | open | high | low | close | adjclose |

static_data
| id  | ticker | name | sector | industry | country | currency |
```

and I'd like to get the holdings for a particular day with the change in price on that day as a calculated field.

I've tried the following query

```
SELECT h.date, 
    h.portfolio, 
    h.instrument, 
    s.name, 
    h.position, 
    p.adjclose AS curpx, 
   (p.adjclose AS lastpx WHERE 
      h.date = "2013-01-10 00:00:00" AND
      h.instrument = p.instrument)

  FROM holdings AS h,   
        static_data AS s, 
        prices AS p 

  WHERE h.date = "2013-01-11 00:00:00" 
    AND h.portfolio = "usequity" 
    AND (h.instrument = p.instrument) 
    AND (h.date = p.date) 
    AND (h.instrument = s.ticker);
```

but I get a syntax error.

```
[2014-11-14 06:11:04] [1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "as": syntax error)
```

I'm a complete N00b at SQL so I'd like to know how I can get two sets of data from the same table and show them side by side or to perform a calculation using one against the other in SQL.

Thanks

Comment: A subquery must be a valid SQL query.

Comment: thanks @CL tried putting a "select" and now it gives me a NULL result. I know that the 2013-1-10 is in the database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT ...,
       p.adjclose AS curpx,
       (SELECT p2.adjclose
        FROM prices AS p2
        WHERE p2.date = datetime(h.date, '-1 days')
          AND p2.instrument = h.instrument
       ) AS lastpx
FROM ...
```